# Prevent iOS from darkening image of pressed button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I assign two separate images for UIControlState.Normal (button released) and UIControlState.Highlighted (button pressed). Both images are accepted, however, while the released image is displayed as is, the pressed image appears darker and maybe more transparent than the original image. It there a way to prevent iOS from modifying image of pressed button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by [UIButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/adjustsImageWhenHighlighted). You can set this to false either in code or in your nib/storyboard file.